Backup an restore Armbian from Banana Pi M5 eMMC
I try alot of thing on my Banana Pi M5.
It's easy to burn an image to eMMC storage.
But i don't want to loose all and i want to backup my Banana Pi and it's not easy...
Like for my Raspberry Pi, i want to make an image of everything really often.
Once the Banana Pi boots on the eMMC memory, it is impossible to boot on the sd card.
So I tried to create the image directly from the Armbian installed on the eMMC storage with the command :
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=1M status=progress | xz > /media/USB/emmc_backup.img.xz
ok, i have my image.
I reset the eMMC with :
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk1
i put an SD card with Ubuntu and i do this command for restoring :
sudo dd if=/media/USB/emmc_backup.img of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=1M
No luck :

Loading, please wait...
Starting systemd-udev version 252.22-1~deb12u1
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done
Being: Running /scripts/init-premount ... (initramfs)

No more
It's the same when i try to duplicate my Banana Pi on an other. Duplicate my Banana Pi it's my final goal but backup it's more important for the moment.
I try to find a solution on internet : everybody burn the eMMC but nobody backup

sudo dd if=/media/USB/emmc_backup.img of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=1M conv=fsync


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
